# Elements display in front of their container, but can't be interacted with

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website and have encountered an interesting problem. I have a container which holds my navbar. For some reason, this container displays behind its contents (Which it should) but mouse interaction acts as if it's in front of its contents.

JSFiddle of my current code
https://jsfiddle.net/qzsxpgrq/

HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div id="bar">
        <div id="navLeft">
            <div class="navL navbutton"><a href="">About</a></div>
            <div class="navL navbutton"><a href="">The Team</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="navLogo">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="http://www.epicyoobed.com/res/img/navLogo.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="navRight">
            <div class="navR navbutton"><a href="">Programs</a></div>
            <div class="navR navbutton"><a href="">Contact</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    font-family: arial;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #BBB;
}
#navbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}
#bar {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url("http://www.epicyoobed.com/res/img/nav.png");
}
#navRight {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#navbar div div a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.current {
    background-image: url("http://www.epicyoobed.com/res/img/nav_sel.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.navL {
    float: right;
}
.navR {
    float: left;
}
.navbutton {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbutton:hover {
    background-image: url("http://www.epicyoobed.com/res/img/nav_sel.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#navLogo {
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}
#logo {
    margin: auto;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
}
#navLeft {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Xetanai Try adding a z-index of 3 to the #navLeft and navRight.

```
#navLeft {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    z-index:3;
}
#navRight {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    width: 45%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index:3;
}
```

The issue you're experiencing is because the logo is 100% width and has a z-index of 2. Effectively placing it above the left and right containers.

Comment: use `z-index: -1000` for that container

Comment: I don't believe that is a solution. This will put the logo behind the navigation which I'm not sure if Xetanai is looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Rodrigo, your suggestion put the logo behind the navbar.

Comment: @RodrigoGomes Might as well use `-10000` while you're at it.

Comment: @divinecomedian yes, any negative value will work, taking in consider that the negative number choosen is the less than any other in the page.